# Replace certain part of a php string

Tags: php

I have some text *(in this specific case `$expression`)*, sometimes it is quite long. I want to output the text the same way it is, except outputting `numbers %` bold. Sometimes its spelled like `3%` and sometimes there's a space like `123 %`.

```
<?php
$expression = 'here we got a number 23 % and so on';
$tokens = "([0-9]+)[:space:]([\%])";
$pattern = '/[0-9][0-9] %/';

$keyword = array($pattern);
$replacement = array("<b>$keyword</b>");
echo preg_replace($keyword, $replacement, $expression);
?>
```

This is what I have but I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong. It outputs an error on the line `$replacement = array("<b>$keyword</b>");` and then outputs the actual string except it replaces the `number%` with `<b>Array</b>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$expression = 'here we got a number 23 % and so on';
var_dump(preg_replace('/(\d+\s*\%)/', "<b>$1</b>", $expression));
```

Answer (score 2):

You face an (unwanted) array to string conversion. In development always make the warnings/notices visible, PHP tells you that this happens (and where).

Also look again on the [*`preg_replace`* manual page](http://php.net/preg_replace), it shows the correct syntax for the replacement. Follow especially the part about *backreferences* in the replacement parameter.

```
$replacement = array("<b>\\0</b>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern and replacement are wrong, you need a group in the pattern in order to have a "variable" placeholder in the replacement. Check the [preg_replace manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for more details.

I created this [gist](https://gist.github.com/danielcsgomes/5423255) with a solution, the code on it:

```
<?php

$expression = 'here we got a number 23 % and so on';
$pattern = '/(\d+ %)/';
$replacement = '<b>$1</b>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $expression);
```